# Weird 240 ohm resistor on zq line to DDR

Tags: resistors, schematics, ddr

I've been looking at schematics that interface ddr ram and noticed a weird notation for their zq pull down resistor. What is with the dot at the top as well as the 1%? Haven't seen this before.

[image: wierdresistor]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because these DDR's have merged drivers and on-chip termination they have an active termination calibration circuitry and procedure.  The calibration resistor should be accurate , thus the 1% selection.

Note that this resistor can be shared amongst die if the controller sequences properly. Look at this app note from Micron [(opens a PDF)](https://www.micron.com/~/media/documents/products/technical-note/dram/tn4102.pdf) concerning the calibration "DDR3 ZQ Calibration".

The dot ... see this [EE.SE post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/208473/11861)

[image]

From that data sheet.

Answer (score 4):

1% is the resistor tolerance (its 'accuracy' value). The actual resistor used in the circuit must have a value that is within 1% of the specified 240R.
The dot may be an orientation indicator of some sort. Could this resistor be one part of a network or package of multiple resistors?